# How get a good approximation, but simple, of $\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\left(\int_2^y\log \zeta(x+iy)dx\right)dy$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I would to learn to calculate some approximation this kind of integrals, here there is an example that I don't know if my approach is good. Is a double integral involving the logarithm of the Riemann Zeta function. Thus I need to say (if I am wrong tell me) that I've consider the main branch of the logarithm.

> **Question.** How one can evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\left(\int_2^y\log \zeta(x+iy)dx\right)dy?$$
> **Many thanks.**

Which I am interested is to find a way to evaluate this numerically. I know that $\zeta(s)$ has an Euler product convergent for $\Re s>1$, thus there is a closed-form for $\log \zeta(x+iy)$. Is it a good way? I wrote calculations for the integral $\int_2^y$,

$$\int_2^y\sum_{p \text{ prime}}\sum_{m=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{m} p^{-mx}e^{-imy\log p}dx=\sum_{p \text{ prime}}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m}e^{-imy\log p} (-\frac{e^{-mx\log p}}{m\log p}\Big|_2^y .$$

Now I know that I can evaluate and integrate (I presume that with a numerical method) finishig our result, that is a double series $\sum_{p \text{ prime}}\sum_{m=1}^\infty$, of terms of the shape $$\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\cdot\text{exponentials }dy.$$  After I need to take some terms $m$`s and primes $p$ to get an approximation doing calculations from a finite double series. Another way could be to use approximation from Taylor series of the functions in our integrand. Of course isn't required to use Euler products, if you know another way I am waiting.

What's is a good way to get an approximation?

> **Calculation.** With code
>
> *integrate (1+4y^2)^(-2)log(RiemannZeta(x+iy))dxdy, from x=2 to y, from y=0 to 10*
>
> I get from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) this approximation $\approx -0.5088+i0.841053.$

I am asking in my **Question**, about an approximation, isn't required so good as previous, I am interested in the theoretical discussion to obtain an approximation, not the best one.

Comment: I presume that I need a numerical mehtod for our second integral, but as I am asking I don't know if an approximation likes WA did, or more simple, only is required a simple approximation, is possible using bounds or asymptotic behaviours in our integrands. What is your method to get a simple approximation? Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: $|\log \zeta(s)-\sum_{p^k < x} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}| < \int_{x-1}^\infty |t^{-s}|dt = \frac{(x-1)^{1-Re(s)}}{1-Re(s)}$

Comment: Many thanks for this NICE inequality. I wait the approach of users, but I will think in it @user1952009

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote and why it is useful here ?

Comment: I belive that you are saying that with your identity one can get the comparison with my calculations, bounding. @user1952009

Comment: How do you use what I wrote for evaluating your $\int$ ?

Comment: I believe that you are saying that I need to start with $$\left| \int_2^y  \log \zeta(x+iy)-\sum_{p^k < x} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}dx\right|<(y-2)\frac{(y-1)^{1-\Re s}}{1-\Re s} .$$ I've combined the well known inequality for the integral ,with your inequality taking $x$ instead of $y$. Is it right @user1952009 ? Or do I combine wrong your claim?

Comment: Not at all I said that $\left| \int_2^y ( \log \zeta(x+iy)-\sum_{p^k < N} \frac{p^{-(x+iy)k}}{k})dx\right|<\int_2^y  \frac{(N-1)^{1-x}}{1-x} dx = ?$

Comment: No, you said the first inequality @user1952009

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote ?

Comment: Yes, now yes,  the last inequality is $|\int_a^b|\leq \int_a^b|\text{integrand}|$ @user1952009

Comment: How can you use it for evaluating your integral ?..

Comment: I know also that I need to say that the tail of our integral is small, and I believe that I need to combine this idea with the triangle inequality and your bound @user1952009, but I have no good abilities.

Comment: Come on... It is trivial what I'm asking. So what formula do you get for evaluating your integral ?

Comment: If you are asking about the closed-form for $$\int_2^y\frac{(N-1)^{1-x}}{1-x} dx ,$$ I don't get now how obtain a result @user1952009

Comment: You don't need a closed-form, but a bound. So what do you get, **again** ?

Comment: I need your knowledges in mathematics, then I will be happy @user1952009 !

Comment: what do you get from what I wrote ?

Comment: One has that $\frac{1}{1-x}<\frac{1}{1-y}$, and the indefinite integral $\int (n-1)^{1-x}dx=-\frac{(n-1)^{1-x}}{\log(n-1)}$. Are you saying to bound by means this way? As you see this is difficult to me @user1952009 . Merci.

Comment: qu'obtiens-tu pour évaluer $\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\left(\int_2^y\log \zeta(x+iy)dx\right)dy$...........

Comment: The final result is a complex number as you see in my **Calculation.** I thanks you if you can add a detailed answer, I can learn a lot of your answers, that I've read @user1952009

Comment: Sérieusement ? Tu ne vois pas que $|\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\left(\int_2^y\log \zeta(x+iy)dx\right)dy-\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\left(\int_2^y\sum_{p^k < N} \frac{p^{-(x+iy)k}}{k}dx\right)dy|< ...$ ?

Comment: Donc qu'obtiens-tu pour les ... ? Et pour $\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\left(\int_2^y\sum_{p^k < N} \frac{p^{-(x+iy)k}}{k}dx\right)dy$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I've did a new step from my claims $$ \left|\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\int_2^y  \frac{(N-1)^{1-x}}{1-x} dx  dy\right| $$
$$<\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{(1+4y^2)^2}\cdot\frac{(1-y)^{-1}}{\log(n-1)} \left( \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{(n-1)^{y-1}} \right) dy.$$

Comment: @user1952009 Haha, you are as frustrating as ever.  You ought to get to the point quicker in comments and explain the details in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @SimpleArt from my viewpoint frustating is when one can not solve his problems. I prefer detailed proofs instead hints in comments, but the viewpoint of user1952009 is this, and it is true that did a lot of actions with same purpose, that I presume that is help as you do in your answers or comments. The problem is the different viewpoint of people with different abilities and mathematical knowledges.

Comment: Yes, and I could tell from personal experience with user1952009.  :-)

Comment: @SimpleArt My perception is that actions from users in this site is like an equilibrium, and an equilibrium is the better. From my viewpoint the importance is the feeback with the whole set of users.

Comment: @user1952009 many thanks also for your patience and help last year, I hope that the next year is a better year for all people. Many thanks.